# How to extract type from empty templated container using decltype?

Tags: c++, templates, types, decltype

What would the correct `decltype` syntax to extract the data type from a specific container class, without recurring to a `value_type` member typedef?

I was attempting to directly access an element with  `decltype<std::declval<myContainerClass>[0]>` but I realize it wouldn't work if the container is empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
std::remove_reference_t<decltype(std::declval<Container>()[0])>
```

Everything inside `decltype` is unevaluated, so the fact that accessing element 0 of a hypothetical empty container is UB doesn't matter. This just extracts the necessary type information from the container's `operator[]`. You need the `remove_reference` because `operator[]` probably returns an lvalue reference.

However, this wouldn't work for a container such as `std::list<T>`. Instead, you can use:

```
typename std::iterator_traits<typename Container::iterator>::value_type
```

If you can't assume `Container::iterator` exists, you can replace `typename Container::iterator` with `decltype(std::declval<Container>().begin())`.

Comment: You can probably also avoid the use of `iterator_traits` by combining the two approaches and dereferencing `begin()`.

Comment: @ChristianRau strictly speaking, that returns `::reference`, which may be some weird proxy type instead of an actual reference.

Comment: But so might `operator[]`, no?

Comment: Thanks. But the same way I do not want to assume a `value_type` member exists, I'm also not sure if `begin()` exists on particular non-STL containers.